# Knockout computed does not auto update

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

The debug console output shows that an option change does change the knockout data and the result of the change can be seen by forcing the computed to run by pressing a button on the last line on the html page but for some reason a `ko.computed` that is displayed on the second last line of the html does not auto update as I would expect.

Any help would be appreciated!

#### Code

[JSFiddle Reference](https://jsfiddle.net/carltonj2000/e4ehL3ne/2/)

```js
function CustomBindingViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.range = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  self.opts = [
    "Functionality, compatibility, pricing - all that boring stuff",
    "How often it is mentioned on Hacker News",
    "Number of gradients/dropshadows on project homepage",
    "Totally believable testimonials on project homepage"
  ];

  self.optionRange = 5;
  self.options = ko.observableArray();
  self.opts.forEach(function(option) {
    self.options.push({
      option: option,
      importance: 2
    });
  });

  self.points = function() {
    var sum = 0;
    var sumStr = "";
    self.options().forEach(function(option) {
      sum += option.importance;
      sumStr += option.importance;
    });
    console.log(sumStr);
    return 10 - sum;
  };
}

ko.applyBindings(new CustomBindingViewModel());
```

```css
.points {
  font-weight: bold;
}
.select {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.1/knockout-min.js"></script>
<h1>Knockout Custom Bindings</h1>
<h2>Which factors affect your technology choices?</h2>

<p>Please distribute <span class="points">10</span> points between the following options.</p>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>Option</td>
      <td>Importance</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach:options">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text:option"></td>
      <td class="select">
        <select data-bind="options:$root.range, value:importance"></select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<p>You've got <span class="points" data-bind="text:points()"></span> points left to use.</p>
<button data-bind="click:$root.points()">Finished</button>
```

Comment: I updated the code to force the computed to calculate when a button is pushed, which works, but still the computed does not compute. Latest code is at https://jsfiddle.net/carltonj2000/e4ehL3ne/3/.

Comment: Please accept my apologies if I'm missing something but I do not see any computed function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the array is an observable array the values in the array are not observable.

Make the `importance` property of the items in the array observable as well since that is what you want to watch.

```js
//...other code removed for brevity

self.options = ko.observableArray();
self.opts.forEach(function(option) {
  self.options.push({option:option, importance:ko.observable(2)}); //<-- NOTE THIS HERE
});

//...other code removed for brevity
```

so that the event fires when `importance` values change.

You would then need to update how the points are calculated.

```js
//...other code removed for brevity

self.points = function() {
  var sum = 0;
  var sumStr = "";
  self.options().forEach(function (option) {
    sum += option.importance(); //<-- NOTE THE BRACES
    sumStr += option.importance(); //<-- NOTE THE BRACES
  });
  console.log(sumStr);
  return 10 - sum;
};

//...other code removed for brevity
```

And Here is the completed [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e4ehL3ne/4/)